# PHP Redirecting correct login to another HTML page?

Tags: php, html

I have a login page which links with a small PHP Database and when the username and password are correct I need it to redirect to 'Welcome.html'. I have tried the header and exit; but it doesn't seem to work?

```
if ($testhash == $hash) 
{
    header( "Location: Welcome.html" );
    //exit; (doesn't work either)
    //echo "login correct\n\n";
}   
else 
{

    echo "login incorrect\n\n";
}
```

Comment: try header("Location: Welcome.html"); remove space

Comment: Use [print_r](http://uk.php.net/print_r) or [echo](http://uk.php.net/echo) inside the if and else. Maybe you are not even in that file. It happend to me several times.

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma: functions can be called with spaces

Comment: [Are you echoing something before sending the headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/1492578)

Comment: Double check the file name Welcome.html ??

Answer (score 0):

Use url please

```
if ($testhash == $hash) 
{
    header( "Location: http://your-url/welcome.html" );
    exit;
}   
else 
{

    echo "login incorrect\n\n";
}
```

Comment: The redirect works with relative urls too. And don't ever forget the exit after redirect. It's a security hole.

Comment: Thank! :) header() exec browser redirect you works with only url, you can't use it for redirect in folder..

Answer (score 0):

1. you should make sure that there is no output (echo, print functions and so on are not alowed) before header function
2. if you use Apache then ModPageSpeed(if active) might do some conflicts

Answer (score -2):

You should use the `header()`function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

The reason your header may not be working is that is has to be right at the top of your PHP file. You also need to use a full URL as the header parameter.

The `header()` function sends header data to the browser and needs to come before any `<html>` input.

For example:

```
<?php
     header( "Location: http://www.example.com/welcome.php" );
     exit;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```